# Running sum over date in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime, cumulative-sum

I have this table, where id_user=7

TABLE

```
7    2018-11-12
7    2018-11-12
7    2018-11-13
7    2018-11-13
7    2018-11-13
7    2018-11-13
7    2018-11-14
7    2018-11-15
7    2018-11-15
7    2018-11-15
7    2018-11-15
7    2018-11-15
7    2018-11-16
7    2018-11-16
7    2018-11-16
7    2018-11-16
7    2018-11-16
7    2018-11-16
7    2018-11-16
```

I want to return the times the user appeared by day, and the cumulative sum of the prior days

I've tried so far...

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM posts
WHERE id_user='7'
GROUP BY DATE(date)
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

```
 day 12/11/2018 > 2 (2)
 day 13/11/2018 > 4 (6)
 day 14/11/2018 > 1 (7)
 day 15/11/2018 > 5 (12)
 day 16/11/2018 > 7 (19)
```

**How do I get the number between parenthesis?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running sums without any window functions or user variables require joining the table with itself and finding out rows that rank lower than current. This is an expensive operation but more reliable than user variables.

```
SELECT main.id_user, main.date, main.c AS today_count, main.c + COUNT(prev.date) AS running_count
FROM (
    SELECT id_user, date, COUNT(*) AS c
    FROM posts
    GROUP BY id_user, date
) AS main
LEFT JOIN posts AS prev ON prev.id_user = main.id_user AND prev.date < main.date
GROUP BY main.id_user, main.date, main.c
ORDER BY main.date DESC
```

There are various ways to write the above query and some might be slightly more efficient than others but expect no miracles on larger data set.

[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=fb34f4ebc709a58ab19d667b056fc0b4)

Comment: I'm curious as to why you think user variables are not reliable?

Comment: These techniques rows to be ordered by some criteria _before_ variables are calculated. However this is something you cannot control and the query which works under one condition may not work under other. See https://mysqlserverteam.com/row-numbering-ranking-how-to-use-less-user-variables-in-mysql-queries/ where author has provided an example of broken results.